# How do you find what place in an array something is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms, radio-button

User edit view:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: :name %>
    <%= f.submit "Save" %>

    <%= f.fields_for :photos do |photo_fields| %>
        <%= image_tag(photo_fields.object.photo.url(:user_thumbnail) %>
        <%= f.radio_button :avatar, @selected_photo_number %>
```

So I show all the photos uploaded by the user and a radio button next to each of them. How can I made it so that when I click the first one @selected = 0 and the second one @selected = 1 and so on. Basically i need to know in which place the photo is in the array @user.photos[]. Thanks!

Instead of `@selected_photo_number` I need something like `photo_fields.object.place` in array??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for `index`.

```
>> array = [1,2,3,4,5]
>> array.index(1) # 0
>> array.index(3) # 2
```

But with your code, i think you're looking for `each_with_index` instead

```
<% f.object.photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :photos, [photo] do |photo_fields| %>
    <%= image_tag(photo_fields.object.photo.url(:user_thumbnail) %>
    <%= f.radio_button :avatar, index %>
```

Comment: heres the answer: <%= f.radio_button :avatar, @user.photos.index(photo_fields.object) %>

Comment: i had been trying to do photo_fields.object.index didn't know the syntax